# Reactjs Load SCSS at runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I have two scss files that contain the variables for different themes in my site.
I want to be able to change the theme by providing a url parameter like this:

```
let _url = new URL(window.location.href);
let _theme = _url.searchParams.get("theme");

switch (_theme) {
  case 'light': import('./styles/config-light.scss'); break;
  default: import('./styles/config-default.scss');
}
```

This works perfectly when I run the site in development, but before the site is pushed to production when build the code.
The problem with the switch statement above, is that the files are not included in the build.

the scss config files contain varaibles like this:

```
$section-background: #373838;
$section-border: #212121;
$toolbar-border: #212121;
$output-background: #313131;
```

Each config file has different values for the different themes, this allows me to not duplicate the css code, only the values.

What would be the best way to acheive this kind of solution that would allow me to load and change the different scss files at runtime? TIA!

Comment: from my knowledge of imports they get hoisted to the very top of the context no matter where you declare them, therefore i believe that switch will actually import both always.

Comment: i would probably suggest using css variables instead of scss variables to control themeing if you're going to change them dynamically because of the nature of css variables being able to be changed programmatically so easily

Comment: @ShanonJackson thank you for the suggestion of css variables, i think this will be the best way to go. What do you mean by "the nature of css variables being able to be changed programmatically"?

Answer (score 0):

As @Shanon Jackson has mentioned both files will be imported.

I'd suggest looking at [Styled components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming), it offers theming that can be controlled at runtime.